# Simple html that shows 1 or 2 columns depending on screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple monitoring website that shows some `rrd` graphs. The graphs are png images created on the fly, but they have fixed dimensions.

What I want is to present them in 1 column if the browser width is below a threshold value, and in 2 columns if the browser internal window width is above that threshold.

From the little html I have taught myself, I know that tables are generated with  amd  clauses (columns are done by the ) and that window width is returned by innerWidth javascript property. What I do not know is how to connect these bits of information to add intelligence for column width.

this is my code

```
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
            <td>
                    <body><center>
                    <h2>CO2: unfiltered values </h2>
                    <p><a href="./index_CO2unf.html"><img src="./ramdisk/htdocs/CO2unf_1h.png" alt="CO2unf_1h.png"/></a></p><p><br></p>
                    <h2>CO2: filtered values </h2>
                    <p><a href="./index_CO2fil.html"><img src="./ramdisk/htdocs/CO2fil_1h.png" alt="CO2fil_1h.png"/></a></p><p><br></p>
                    <h2>O2: partial pressure O2 values</h2>
                    <p><a href="./index_O2pp.html"><img src="./ramdisk/htdocs/O2pp_1h.png" alt="O2pp_1h.png"/></a></p><p><br></p>
            </td>                                                                                                                
            <td> 
                    <h2>O2: percentage O2 values</h2>
                    <p><a href="./index_O2pct.html"><img src="./ramdisk/htdocs/O2pct_1h.png" alt="O2pct_1h.png"/></a></p><p><br></p>
                    <h2>O2: Temperature values</h2>                                                                                 
                    <p><a href="./index_O2temp.html"><img src="./ramdisk/htdocs/O2temp_1h.png" alt="O2temp_1h.png"/></a></p><p><br></p>
                    <h2>O2: Pressure values</h2>                                                                                       
                    <p><a href="./index_O2pres.html"><img src="./ramdisk/htdocs/O2pres_1h.png" alt="O2pres_1h.png"/></a></p><p><br></p>
            </body>                                                                                                                    
            </td>  
    </tr>
```

the central `</td><td>` code is what I need to remove when browser width is below a threshold.

how can I do that?

Comment: I would stay away from tables, they're not necessary. Look into [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to specify how many columns there are at different sizes.

Comment: Here is how I would do it https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/esptpmwk/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove your table and just go with 2 `<div>`'s using `@media` queries like this: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/esptpmwk/3/

```
body{margin: 0;}
div{width: 50%; height: 600px; float: left; text-align: center;}
.div-1{background-color: blue;}
.div-2{background-color: red;}
@media (max-width: 650px){
    div{width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: how there, how can I update the above to get a 2nd css that does the same two to one column transition but at a different width..?

Comment: @nass I will help you but I am not sure I understand what you want.

Comment: its ok I got it. i added 2 @media entries. where I changed the "div" to ".div-X" and i changed the "max-width" as well. so now double columns of different elements will unify in different widths. see here https://jsfiddle.net/esptpmwk/13/#&togetherjs=QopIURt3Io . the light blue is dimensioned from the left text column. so the bigger right column goes out of the lightblue boundaries. how can I get the box dimensions from the larger column ?

Comment: @nass I updated your fiddle, and added some easy javascript, it now will pick the highest div and set the smaller div to the same size:  https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/esptpmwk/14/

Comment: Hm, I do not understand the clause `<div class="div-2" id="div-1">` . How should I read it ? and what is run first? the html code or the javascript part?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this markup (simplified for demonstration):

```css
.two-across {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.two-across:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  clear: left;
}
.cleared {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-across">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600/technics/1"></p>
</div>
<div class="two-across">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600/technics/2"></p>
</div>
<div class="two-across">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600/technics/3"></p>
</div>
<div class="two-across">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600/technics/4"></p>
</div>
<div class="two-across">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600/technics/5"></p>
</div>
<div class="two-across">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600/technics/6"></p>
</div>
<!-- clearing div should appear after floated elements -->
<div class="cleared"></div>
```

Comment: could you elaborate on `.two-across:nth-child(2n + 1) ` ?

Comment: In earlier answer I suggested adding `<br>` tags after every two rows. In revised answer I use floats + clear to display up to two items in each row without manual line breaks. `.two-across:nth-child(2n + 1)  { clear ... }` rule forces every odd numbered box (1, 3, 5, ...) on a new line. You can remove it to fit as many boxes on each line as possible.